# Can one Exchange server be set up for site mailboxes with multiple SharePoint farms?

Tags: exchange-server, site-mailboxes

We are setting up site mailboxes but would like to configure and test it in our QA SharePoint environment first.  We don't have a QA Exchange 2013 server, so would be using our production one, and just need to make sure that it won't impact our ability to configure site mailboxes on production SharePoint after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this.Reason why i am saying is, you have to build the trust between Exchange and SharePoint. SharePoint will only communicate via his own trust.
One thing make sure, use the different name convention for each farm. You can use QA keyword for your QA trust and configuration.

Use the Prod keyword in the Prod configuration.